# Who knows what this brown fruit with one date-like pit is called?

Tags: fruit, food-identification

It has a slightly thick skin like an apple, semi-dry and grainy texture, with a slight apple flavor, about the size of a large grape, with one pit, reminiscent of that of a date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those look like [jujubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jujube)

Comment: I'd call them delicious looking :)

Comment: I agree with @sourd'oh - the fruit and the foliage look exactly like jujube. However, every time I had the fruit it has been much riper, brown and mushy.

Answer (score 9):

Those look like jujubes (not to be confused with the candy). They're also known as Chinese dates, and are frequently found dried.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I have discovered the Jujube!

Answer (score 6):

These are jujubes.

We find them mostly in the  Mediterranean region starting from like 500 m height(I have one of these tree in my garden).

You should just be careful if there is no holes made by worms in there, then you souldn't eat it. It's not poisonous but it will probably taste bad. To know, you bite it in the middle to check.

It grows during the end of august and start of september.

It's not too sweet unless it's dried up.

They are red when grown and green when not. Some are both: part green, part red.

Answer (score 3):

i'm from india and we use this fruit for festivals,widely known here.
we called it as indian Jujube.
This also known as Ber.
 Chinee Apple, Jujube, Indian plum and Masau is a tropical fruit tree species belonging to the family Rhamnaceae.

Answer (score 3):

Hope its not too late an answer but they are called Masawu here in zim and am having some right now. They have a slimish feel in the mouth sort of like okra slime but tasty sweet to sour depending on the tree. worms love them too so if you mind look out for them. If you are like me anything that eats fruit is edible.

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote, but note the Internet says that Masawu is just another name for Jujube, which has been suggested a few times. http://thesovereignstate.org/indigenous-fruits-of-zimbabwe-3/

Comment: And swe's answer mentions "masau" which looks like a slightly different spelling of your "masawu"

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Turkey and it's a widely known fruit here.

- We call it "iğde",
- English dictionary calls it:

  1. "**oleaster**(kitchen)"
  2. "**eleagnus**(botanical)".

Comment: The fruits do in deed look right. However, from the leaves in the photo above I would not agree with you. The leaves look very much like typical Rhamnaceae leaves ... which would support sourd'oh's jujube theory.

Comment: Yes, I had the idea that it might be an oleaster but pretty sure now that its not. Because oleaster are sweet and they dont have an apple flavour. Im joining the jujube camp.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lotus, or to be specific: [Diospyros lotus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date-plum) More commonly known as **date-plum**. (Hence the pit as you noticed).

If you taste them, they have a chalky texture with hints of sweetness.  They usually have a great aroma and smell.  They are also good dried with tea.